# NoSuchMethodError: org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/util/MRJobConfUtil.setTaskLogProgressDeltaThresholds

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

I am getting the following error while executing a mapreduce job in my hadoop cluster (distributed cluster).

I found the error below in the application logs in Yarn where the mapper fails.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/util/MRJobConfUtil.setTaskLogProgressDeltaThresholds(Lorg/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration;)V (loaded from file:/data/hadoop/yarn/usercache/hdfs-user/appcache/application_1671477750397_2609/filecache/11/job.jar/job.jar by sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@8bf41861) called from class org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl
```

Comment: Additionally, I found the error below in the application logs in Yarn where the mapper fails.       
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/util/MRJobConfUtil.setTaskLogProgressDeltaThresholds(Lorg/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration;)V (loaded from file:/data/hadoop/yarn/usercache/hdfs-user/appcache/application_1671477750397_2609/filecache/11/job.jar/job.jar by sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@8bf41861) called from class org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl

Comment: That is your real error, not slf4j. Please show your gradle file. Also tell us what version of hadoop you're using (your error indicates your mapreduce JAR depends on the wrong Hadoop version). FWIW, [I have used Gradle fine](https://github.com/OneCricketeer/mapreduce-sandbox#mapreduce-sandbox). But no one really writes MapReduce code anymore. Have you considered using Spark with YARN?

Comment: The hadoop version is Hadoop 3.3.0. I have used Spark with YARN, but this a legacy code base where I am making some changes. Please find my gradle below respective comment sections.

Comment: implementation  (group: 'org.apache.hadoop', name: 'hadoop-client', version:'3.0.0-cdh6.1.0'){
        exclude group: 'org.slf4j', module: 'slf4j-log4j12'
        exclude group: 'ch.qos.logback', module: 'logback-classic'
    }

    implementation  group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-core_2.11', version:'2.4.0-cdh6.1.0'
    compileOnly group: 'org.json4s', name: 'json4s-jackson_2.11', version:'3.5.3'
    compileOnly group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version:'2.9.5'

Comment: compileOnly(group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module', name: 'jackson-module-scala_2.11', version:'2.9.5') {
        exclude(module: 'guava')
    }
   implementation "org.apache.avro:avro:1.11.0"
    implementation  group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version:'20.0'
    implementation  group: 'joda-time', name: 'joda-time', version:'2.8.1'
 implementation 'org.assertj:assertj-joda-time:2.2.0'
 implementation group: 'org.javatuples', name: 'javatuples', version: '1.2'
 implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat', name: 'jackson-dataformat-yaml', version: '2.12.4'

Comment: implementation  group: 'net.alchim31.maven', name: 'scala-maven-plugin', version:'3.3.1'
    implementation  group: 'org.scalactic', name: 'scalactic_2.11', version:'3.0.5'
    testImplementation group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: "$junit4Version"
    testImplementation group: 'org.scalatest', name: 'scalatest_2.11', version:'3.0.5'
    implementation group: 'org.projectlombok', name: 'lombok', version: "$lombokVersion"
    testImplementation group: 'org.projectlombok', name: 'lombok', version: "$lombokVersion"

Comment: Please [edit] and format your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The hadoop version is Hadoop 3.3.0

Okay, [that method exists in that version](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/branch-3.3.0/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/util/MRJobConfUtil.java#L75), but not [3.0.0](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/branch-3.0.0/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/util/MRJobConfUtil.java)

Therefore, you need to use `hadoop-client` dependency of that version, not `3.0.0-cdh6...`. Also, use `compileOnly` with it not `implementation`. This way, it is not confliciting with what YARN already has on its classpath.

Similarly, `spark-core` would have the same problem, and if you have Spark in your app anyway, then use it, not MapReduce functions.

---

Run `gradle dependencies`, then search for hadoop libraries and ensure they are 3.3.0

Comment: I modified it to the following. However, I am getting the same error.                                                     `compileOnly group: 'org.apache.hadoop', name: 'hadoop-client', version: '3.3.0'`

Comment: What if you `exclude group 'org.apache.hadoop'` from `spark-core`? Or remove that, if you are not using Spark...

Comment: Thank you so much. I removed the spark-core and a bunch of other unused packages. The avro stuff and nett.io stuff were somehow being referred from the spark-core package. I replaced them with the the avro-mapred and io.netty package. The previous errors are gone. I am now left with a different error which I need to troubleshoot.